# VBA Excel Macro that allows to compare 2 Excel worksheets and copy differences in a third worksheets?

Tags: excel, vba, compare, worksheet

I'm beginner with VBA code. I'm looking for help in writing code that can compare 2 Excel worksheets and copy differences in a new worksheet. In the third worksheet, I would to add a column indicating if there is added data, removed data or change between sheet 1 and sheet 2.

Here is an example of what I'm looking for given 2 sheets of data and the final output :

Sheet1 "Update" :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uEcy.png)

Sheet2 "Original" : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MSup.png)

Sheet3 "Result"  : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ru062.png)

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Depending on your version of Excel, you could probably use the Inquire add-in to do this.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but could you be more precise on what I shall do. Thanks.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-you-can-do-with-spreadsheet-inquire-ebaf3d62-2af5-4cb1-af7d-e958cc5fad42